# How to Access method decorated with @action decorator of a view inherited from APIView Class in urls.py file in DRF?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need to apply different permission on different methods of my View class which is inherited from APIView in a DRF application. To achieve this I am using @action decorator on my methods of view.

Here is views.py code

```py
class UserView(APIView):

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False, permission_classes=[AllowAny])
    def create(self, request):
        serializer = UserRegSerializer(data=request.data)
        user_service = UserService()
        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serialized_data = serializer.validated_data
            registered_user = user_service.create_user(serialized_data)
            payload = registered_user.__dict__
            response = ResponseGenerator(payload, constants.SUCCESS_KEY)
        except Exception as e:
            response = ResponseGenerator(e)
        return Response(data={"Response": response.get_custom_response()})
```

I am not getting that how could I access this method in my urls.py file against the pattern '/user', here is my urls.py code.

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('user', UserView.as_view()),
]
```

I was using ChatGPT to answer this query of mine. It suggested some ways to use a dictionary object passed {'post':'create'} in as_view() method of View in urls.py as following.

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('user', UserView.as_view({'post':'create'})),
]
```

In this it told me that **key** of the dictionary should be the http method used to access that method against the url pattern and **value** of dictionary should be the method which you want to access against the given url.

But its not working, and gives me following error when I try to start my project after writing this code in my urls.py

> TypeError: APIView.as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I didn't find any solution to solve the problem that I am facing anywhere on Internet and in django's documentation as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using Generic(Some Method)APIView.
Because it can be changed to something good for your code scalability and reliability.

1. Use `CreateAPIView`, you don't need to decorator for basic create function.

```py
# views.py
class UserRegView(CreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = UserRegSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
```

2. If you need validation, write at the validate function.
   Your Response could be change sometime. Then, you should change you

```py
# serializers.py
class UserRegSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    somefield_1 = serializers.CharField()
    somefield_2 = serializers.CharField()
    newfield_1 = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)  # example

    def validate(self, attrs):

        a = attrs["somefield_1"]
        if a != "otherthing":
            raise ValidationError({"error": "Your error description some case"})
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = UserReg.objects.create(**validated_data)

        # Make Logic for instance or just validated_data or custom response whatever you want.
        # If you want to custom response, could write like this simple example.
        return {
            "somefield_1": "test1",
            "somefield_2": "test1",
            "newfield_1": "test1",
        }
```

3. Now, you don't need any argument in as_view().

```py
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path("user_new", UserRegView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: So, you are basically saying there is no way calling multiple methods of same APIView in the urls.py ?

Comment: @RIO
No. You can call multiple methods by using same APIView. I recommend to using generic view like ListCreateAPIView when you multiple[Get, Post] method.
This is document about Generic Views. 

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

Now you can you multiple method in same View.